# Continue loop inside loop

Tags: php

I have while loop inside another while loop and inside another while loop.
This echoes products by categories and categories by groups. Simplified example code is below:

```
$a=0;
while(2 > $a) {
    echo "<div><h3>Group</h3>";
    $b=0;
    while(5 > $b) {
        echo "<label>Category</label>";
        echo "<select name='productID_".$b."'>";
        $c=0;
        while(10 > $c) {
            echo "<option>product</option>";
            $c++;
        }
        echo "</select><br/>";
        $b++;
    }
    echo "</div>";
    $a++;
}
```

What I need is that select name continues in another group and doesn't start from 0 again.
For example now if I have 2 groups with 2 product categories each then in first group select names will be `productID_0` and `productID_1` but in second group also. I need it in second to continue with `productID_2` and `productID_3`.

How to do that?

Comment: Don't reset `$b` to `0` every time through the outer loop.

Comment: I know thats the problem but don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different variable for the number in the HTML than you're using for the loop control:

```
$i = 0;
for ($a = 0; $a < 2; $a++) {
    echo "<div><h3>Group</h3>";
    for ($b = 0; $b < 5; $b++) {
        echo "<label>Category</label>";
        echo "<select name='productID_".$i."'>";
        $i++;
        for ($c = 0; $c < 10; $c++) {
            echo "<option>product</option>";
        }
        echo "</select><br/>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

BTW, `for` loops are the more usual idiom for looping like this, as it allows you to see the whole structure in one place.

Alternatively, you could use `name='productID[]'`, rather than giving them distinct names. When the form is submitted, `$_POST['productID']` will then contain an array of all the values.

Comment: I tried that but then my second group is not echoed